# Is it possible to switch jar files during runtime?

Tags: android, jar

I want to create a jar file that will contain logic for an Android app.

With this Android app I want it to be able to delete and download a new jar file if an update is available and then use the methods in that class.

The name of the methods in the class of the jar file will remain the same but the logic could change.

Is it something that is possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible but:

From [Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/malicious-behavior/)

**The following are explicitly prohibited:**

- Viruses, trojan horses, malware, spyware or any other malicious
  software.
- Apps that link to or facilitate the distribution or installation of malicious software.
- **Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or native code, from a source other than Google Play.**
- Apps that introduce or exploit security vulnerabilities.
- Apps that steal a user’s authentication information (such as usernames or passwords) or that mimic other apps or websites to trick users into disclosing personal or authentication information.
- Apps that install other apps on a device without the user’s prior consent.
- Apps designed to secretly collect device usage, such as commercial spyware apps.